# Why is logrotate not rotating logs Tomcat access logs on aws centos 6.3?

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, cron, log-files, logrotate

I have the following file in `/etc/logrotate.d`:

```
/usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/*.access {
nodateext
copytruncate
daily
rotate 7
notifempty
postrotate
EXT=`date --date='-1 day' +%Y-%m-%d`
/bin/gzip $1.1
mv $1.1.gz  $1.$EXT.log.gz
endscript
create 0640 tomcat tomcat
}
```

It should take a file servername.access and move it to servername.access.2013.02.24.log.gz

When I run manually `sudo /usr/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat` it works
From inside the cron daily it does not work

contents of /var/lib/logrotate.status

```
logrotate state -- version 2
"/var/log/yum.log" 2013-1-1
"/var/log/up2date" 2012-12-12
"/var/log/sssd/*.log" 2012-12-12
"/var/log/dracut.log" 2013-1-1
"/var/log/httpd/*log" 2013-2-12
"/var/log/wtmp" 2012-12-12
"/var/log/spooler" 2013-2-24
"/usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access" 2013-2-24
"/var/log/btmp" 2013-2-12
"/var/log/rhsm/rhsmcertd.log" 2013-2-24
"/var/log/maillog" 2013-2-24
"/var/log/php-fpm/error.log" 2013-2-24
"/var/log/cups/*_log" 2012-12-12
"/var/log/secure" 2013-2-24
"/var/log/rhsm/rhsm.log" 2013-2-24
"/var/log/messages" 2013-2-24
"/var/account/pacct" 2012-12-12
"/var/log/cron" 2013-2-24
```

output of `/var/log/cron`:

```
Feb 24 00:48:01 AWS001 run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[13433]: starting logrotate
Feb 24 00:48:02 AWS001 run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[13457]: finished logrotate
```

Has somebody an idea?

Comment: Have you checked user/group permissions on the logs? Can the user running logrotate access them and do something with them?

Comment: Since logrotate write to the folder from outside the cron, I don't think that is the problem. I nevertheless chmod the log folder to +w, I will let you know tomorrow if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work

```
sudo crontab -u root -l (list jobs for user root in cron)
There was no jobs
sudo crontab -u root -e (edit crontab)
@daily /usr/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat  >/dev/null 2>&1
save the file
sudo crontab -u root -l
one job for user root
```

I also added full paths in /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat as indicated by user quanta

Note: when you cat /etc/crontab it is still empty

I found my job in file /var/spool/cron/root
Thanks to all who answered

Answer (score 0):

logrotate -d /path/tologrotate.conf

(NB: not your fragment file, the top level one that includes it)

Output of that can be helpful.

excerpt of sudo  /usr/sbin/logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf
after I set the date one day backwards inside /var/lib/logrotate.status (otherwise it says nothing to rotate)

```
rotating pattern: /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/*.access  after 1 days (7 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access
  log needs rotating
rotating log /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access, log->rotateCount is 7
dateext suffix '-20130225'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.7 to /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.8 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 7), 
renaming /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.6 to /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.7 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 6), 
renaming /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.5 to /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.6 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 5), 
renaming /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.4 to /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.5 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 4), 
renaming /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.3 to /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.4 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 3), 
renaming /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.2 to /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.3 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.1 to /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.2 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.0 to /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.1 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 0), 
copying /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access to /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.1
truncating /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access
running postrotate script
running script with arg /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access: "
EXT=`/bin/date --date='-1 day' +%Y-%m-%d`
/bin/gzip $1.1
/bin/mv $1.1.gz  $1.$EXT.log.gz
"
removing old log /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.8
error: error opening /usr/share/apache-tomcat/logs/AWS001.access.8: No such file or directory
```

Comment: sudo  /usr/sbin/logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf

Answer (score 0):

> When I run manually `sudo /usr/sbin/logrotate -v
>   /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat` it works From inside the cron daily it does
>   not work

Keep in mind that you should always use the absolute path in the cron, so try this:

```
EXT=`/bin/date --date='-1 day' +%Y-%m-%d`
/bin/gzip $1.1
/bin/mv $1.1.gz $1.$EXT.log.gz
```

Comment: I am trying your code